# Why we need a index route under any route in ember js?

Tags: ember.js

I am recently learning ember js. But one thing I don't understand is why, for all regular routes, there is always a default child route "index" with it. Why we need it? Is there any use case for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the `index` route, you could show content that's not visible for child routes. For example following router:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('parent', function () {
    this.route('child');
  });
});
```

The parent template:

```
<p>I am the parent<br>
This template is visible if a user visits both /parent and /parent/child routes</p>

{{outlet}}
```

The parent.index template

```
<p>I am still the parent<br>
This template is only visible if a user visits the /parent route<</p>
```

The parent.child template

```
<p>I am the child<br>
This template is only visible if a user visits the /parent/child route</p>
```

**Note:** both the parent.index template and the child template are both rendered within the `{{outlet}}`!

Answer (score 0):

The index route is the main route you enter into whenever enter a route. For example, you enter /blogs, the template that's loaded is the blogs.index template.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding, you can check http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/route/post and play with Tree view by clicking on the particular nodes, and you can see the,

- URL
- Route
- Controller
- Template Template Outline (where this will show
  hierarchy of templates)
- Route Hooks( Validation phase hooks[`beforeModel()`,`model()`,`afterModel()`] and
  setup phase hook[`activate()`,`setupController()`,`renderTemplate()`]).

I am just attempting to explain,

By default if you haven't define any routes,

```
Router.map(function() {
});
```

You will be having `application` and `index` route by default. Always remember that **parent route has no URL**, You will always be in a child state of this route (e.g. application.index).

If you got child route then you should definitely have `{{outlet}}` in parent template so that child template will be displayed parent template outlet.

Here you can't visit application route alone, if you say URL is `/` then it means `application.index` route, so it will run `application` route hooks and `index` hooks. and it will render `application.hbs` and will render`index.hbs` in `{{outlet}}` of the `application.hbs`.